# Change destination for multiple hyperlinks

Tags: adobe-indesign

I have a document with a lot of hyperlinks and some of them point to the same place. A very simple example, just to show what I mean:

> Plese visit **the website of our company**. You can find a lot of useful things on **our website**.

Here, both "the website of our company" and "our website" lead to https://site.xyz. I need a way to change "https://site.xyz" to "https://site.abc" in one place so that all links will be automatically updated.

It seems there is some way for it:

- https://creativepro.com/topic/hyperlinks-using-the-same-url-multiple-times/ (The linked video is long and is not free)
- https://creativepro.com/fixing-multiple-hyperlinks-at-once/ (I simply don't understand what Mike mean. This is probably because I use InDesign CS6 while his article is written for a newer version).

... but how?

An image as requested by Janus Bahs Jacquet:

[image]

Comment: What is it you don’t understand in the last link? Quite a few people here no longer have access to CS6, so a screenshot of what the hyperlinks panel and destination options look like on your machine would be useful.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I have added the image to the question. The image is actually almost the same as the one by Mike. The issue that I don't understand the following directions: _"In the dialog box, choose the destination you want to edit and update its name and/or URL"_. It seems I need to repeat it for each link of the destination in question, so I don't see how it saves me from a lot of manual work.

Comment: Related: https://creativepro.com/indesign-cc-9-2-brings-hyperlink-relief/

Comment: ... So yes, the work with hyperlinks was greatly improved since CS6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is fairly straight forward. Although your third link explains it, there may not be enough detail for everyone.

- Highlight the hyperlinks containing the destination to alter in the **Hyperlinks Panel**
- Choose `Hyperlink Options` from the pop out menu on the **Hyperlinks Panel**
- Insert a new URL, and tick the `Shared Hyperlink Destination` option
- Click <kbd>OK</kbd>

[image]

<sub>(CS6 animation)</sub>

All the destinations will update accordingly.

Comment: This works for me, thanks, but it seems that although you say _"Although your third link explains it, there may not be enough detail for everyone."_ - it seems it is not actually the same way as Mike do it. He mentions selecting "**Hyperlink Destination** Options" and not "**Hyperlink** Options". Also, there is no such image in my case as this one by Mike: https://creativepro.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/2019-05-02.png (the bottom one)

Comment: Well, it explains it `:)` But yes, Adobe is known to slightly alter menu wording or dialog windows. This really has more to do with *how* hyperlinks were initially configured - as shared destinations or not. - If everything is a shared destination, you can update that shared destination. But I don't believe the *destination* options will convert a non-shared to a shared destination.